# Understand Johnson Neyman-plot in regard to significant regression terms

Tags: r, statistical-significance, data-visualization, interaction

I'm modelling the relationship between several parameters like `humidity`, `temperature`, `carbon monoxide` and the response `Resistance` of a gas sensor:

```
lm(log(Resistance) ~ (log(CO) + rH + T)^3, data = df)
```

I also take into account their interactions and the regression object reveals that, e.g., the interaction between carbon monoxide and temperature is significant.

Now, I stumbled over these quite interesting Johnson Neyman plots and performed one:

[image: plot]

and it shows no significant influence of temperature on carbon monoxide to affect the response.

The Johnson Neyman-plot provides information about two-way interactions in such a way that it reveals how the one predictor influences the other. To be more precise: Sometimes, the one predictor influences the response only when another predictor exceeds a certain value. This plot shows this circumstance and when there is a significant influence from predictor1 on predictor2, the assigned region/curve will be colored accordingly.
Here, in this case, the plot shows when `CO_part_l` has an influence on the sensor response in dependence on the `T_amb`. For example, one could expect that `CO_part_l` has no influence on the sensor response below a temperature of 70 °C or so. Then the curve below would be red, and above 70 °C it would be green.
More details here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/interactions/vignettes/interactions.html

Hence, I interpret the plot such that `CO_part_l` has no influence on the sensor response (which is not true as it is built for this purpose)..?

Comment: What is the statistical question here? We don't have your data and many of us will have no idea of what the science or engineering is here.

Comment: As I said, I wonder why that plot is showing no significant region. I described that I study the influence of humidity, temperature,..  on the response of a sensor (which is resistance and lowers the higher the gas concentration is).

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think you give readers any basis to answer that question. The details are welcome but they don't in practice change the question from "Why don't I get a significant relationship?".

Comment: I suggest that you add a short paragraph explaining what the Johnson Neyman-Plot shows.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly I can or should add. Maybe, because I'm too deep in my own data.. are you missing more information about the data or about the statistical performing I try to do?
I'll add some information about the plot schematically.

Comment: This model has many terms, up to and including a three-way interaction: what evaluations have you performed to check that you are not overfitting your data?  In particular, how does your model compare to the one without the three-way interaction?  `lm(log(Resistance) ~ (log(CO) + rH + T)^3 - log(CO):rH:T, X)`

Comment: As far as I can tell it performs slightly worse